# Agregar imagen al boton html en ccs

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código hecho:

Html

```
<input type="button" value="Nuevo Proyecto" class = "add">
        <input type="button" value="Ver Proyectos" class = "see">
        <input type="button" value="Administrar Usuarios" class = "adm">
        <input type="button" value="Nuevo Proyecto" class = "new">
```

Aquí el ccs

```
.add{
    background-image: url('/Fuentes/Iconos/add.svg');
}
```

Quisiera agregar la imagen a los botones y centrarla pero no he podido  hacerlo funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```css
<style>
    .btn{
        background-image:url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/256/add-1-icon.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:60px;
        width:70px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
        background-position:center;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<button class="btn">hola</button>
```

También podrías hacerlo simplemente con *HTML*:

```html
<button class="btn">
    <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/256/add-1-icon.png" width="50px">
</button>
```